# Number of ways they can be seated?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

3 boys $B_i ,\  i = 1, 2, 3$ and 6 girls $G_i, \  i = 1, 2, \ldots, 6$ are to be seated in a row. Number of ways they can be seated so that $B_1$ and $B_2$ are separated and $G_1$ and $G_2$ are also separated equal to?

I used the following approach:

Total no of ways - (No of ways $G_1$ , $G_2$ and $B_1$ , $B_2$ are together + No of ways $B_1$ , $B_2$ are together + No of ways $G_1$ , $G_2$ are together)

Which equals: 9! - (7!*2 *2  + 8!*2  + 8!*2)

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you find the number of ways they can be seated with the two boys next to each other?  Subtract that, and...  But ....

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have tried and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the particular difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M$ be the event that number of ways $A_1$ and $A_2$ are together and $N$ be the event that number of ways $B_1$ and $B_2$ are together. Also, let $n(K)$ be the number of ways event $K$ can occur. Apply inclusion-exclusion principle to get,
\begin{align*}
\text{Required answer}&=9!-n(M\cup N)\\
&=9!-n(M)-n(N)+n(M\cap N)\\
&=9!-(2\times8!)-(2\times8!)+(4\times 7!)&&(\text{Using tie method})\\
&=7!(72-16-16+4)\\
&=\boxed{44\times7!}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but the number of ways G1 and G2 are together includes the cases where both G1 and G2 are together and B1 and B2 are together.  Similarly the number of ways B1 and B2 are together includes the cases where both G1 and G2 are together and B1 and B2 are together.  You have subtracted the case where both pairs are together twice, so you have to add it back in once.  This is an example of the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).